# Is a Thomist possible modal proposition a non-judicative proposition?

Tags: logic, aquinas

According to Thomist philosophy and logic, is a possible modal proposition (either divisive or compound) a non-judicative proposition? It would seem to me that the other three modal propositions (necessity, impossibility, and contingent) are all judicative.

However, I can not see how the mode of “possibility” can be judicative. For if truth and falsity are in composition and in division before assent, as in their state of possibility only, and if the intellect suspends its assent, the composition is neither true nor false. The truth or falsity obtains in an enunciation, i.e., in a composition or division, only after the judgment by which it is declared to be conformed or non-conformed with reality. Only then can I see the mode of “possibility” being non-judicative.